# StackOverFlow Exception using Background Thread in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, stack-overflow, background-thread

i'm using a background Thread in vb.net to connect/reconnect to a device.
It's working fine, but after around 2 hours, the programm is throwing a stackoverflow exception, in the following part of my code:

```
if connected = True then
   Thread.Sleep(500)
   Exit sub
endif
```

After that, i'm calling the Sub again.

I know, i could just set the Sleep-Time to e.g. 1000 ms, but i think this isnt the nicest solution...
Would a "Backgroundworker" (using visual studio) be the better solution/ solve my Problem?
Or is there a posibility to clean the stack?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

```
Module connection
    Public Sub connect()
        connect_loop()
        connect()
    End Sub

Public sub connect_loop()
    if connected = True Then
         **HERE IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN**
         Thread.Sleep(500)
         Exit Sub
    Endif

    'Code for the Connection (ping, open Socket etc.)....

End Sub
```

End module

The module is started from my main routine as a background thread:

```
Public background As New Thread(AddressOf connection.connect)
background.IsBackground = True
background.Start()
```

Do you need the Code for the connection? I didn't wrote it here, because the Exception is not thrown in the real connection part. Also, 2 hours everything works fine.

Comment: We need more informations/code to better understand where the problem is: in any case I don't think the solution may be to clean the stack (is never a solution), you need to understand what is impiling up into the stack and solve the problem at it's root

Comment: There is no particular reason why running a subroutine, finishing it, and then running the same one again should cause a stackoverflow. I think your problem lies elsewhere, in code that you have not shown us.

Comment: I added some more code. Is this enough or do you need more details?

Answer (score 1):

Your method `connect` is recursive without any condition under which it will return.

Each call to a function or method will make use of some stack space, and each thread only has so much stack space.

If you want `connect` to loop for ever just use an infinite loop (but consider how the lop will exit when you want to stop the process).

Comment: So you mean, i could just start connect() as a background thread, and put an endless loop in this method? Without calling another method all the time?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub connect()
   ...
   connect()
End Sub
```

So which part of the obvious stack overflow is unclear to you? You are calling `connect` recursively w/o any criteria. It will stack overflow, guaranteed. Your `Sleep()` only delays the inevitable. Threading has nothing to do with the problem. You may want to do somehting like a loop instead:

```
while(true)
 connect_loop()
end
```

(or whatever is the VB syntax for a while loop).

Comment: So you mean, i could just start connect() as a background thread, and put an endless loop in this method? Without calling another method all the time?

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it could raise any error or exception, using the while(true) loop? I'm a bit afraid of overloading my application or somethin else? Is there anything bad about using a While(true) loop to make sure, that my application is always connected or reconnect itself? And do i need the sleep timer?